# Type mismatch: inferred type is GoogleSignInAccount? but GoogleSignInAccount was expected > Task :app:buildInfoGeneratorFdroidDebug

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I am trying to add google sign-in to my kotlin but I am getting error at "user_account". It says "Type mismatch: inferred type is GoogleSignInAccount? but GoogleSignInAccount was expected" 
How to rectify this error?

```
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            val task: Task<GoogleSignInAccount> = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
            try {
                val user_account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(user_account)
            } catch (e: ApiException) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Google sign in failed:(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent` is a Java method, so it can return Nullable object, but Non-null type is specified. So you should either specify your type as `Task<GoogleSignInAccount?>` or use one of possible ways to cast an object to Non-null type.

You can read more about that [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html).

Comment: the first method is not working, is there any other method?

Comment: @BhavnaHaritsa You can try to cast Nullable object to Non-null type (see link in the answer) or provide more specific information about the appeared error.

Answer (score 2):

This maybe a late answer, but hopefully it can help the Kotlin beginners like me in the future.

I met exactly the same error, and modify as the following part to fix it:

```
            val user_account : GoogleSignInAccount? = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(user_account!!)
```

You may refer to Kotlin online document [Null Safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) for the details about null and "!!" operator.