# How to fix "Expected type mismatch: inferred type is GoogleSignInAccount? but GoogleSignInAccount was expected" error?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, google-api, google-signin

When setting up Google Authentication using Kotlin, the following error arises: "Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is GoogleSignInAccount? But GoogleSignInAccount was expected". The error is coming from line 
"val account: GoogleSignInAccount = completedTask.getResult(ApiException::class.java)" 
This code is coming almost in its entirety from https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in

I have checked a question posted on here with the exact same problem but answers to that one couldn't solve my problem (nor her's [Type mismatch: inferred type is GoogleSignInAccount? but GoogleSignInAccount was expected > Task :app:buildInfoGeneratorFdroidDebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677077/type-mismatch-inferred-type-is-googlesigninaccount-but-googlesigninaccount-was)).

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {

```
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        val task: Task<GoogleSignInAccount> = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
        handleResult (task)
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Problem in execution order :(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
private fun handleResult (completedTask: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>) {
    try {
        val account: GoogleSignInAccount = completedTask.getResult(ApiException::class.java) #error in this line
        updateUI (account)
    } catch (e: ApiException) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

If anyone has suggestions on what the cause of this error could be, that would be great.

Comment: just change `val account: GoogleSignInAccount` to `val account: GoogleSignInAccount?`

Comment: ...or remove the explicit type entirely. You don't need type declarations if they can be inferred from assignment.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe a late answer, but hopefully it can help the Kotlin beginners like me in the future.

I met exactly the same error, and modify as the following part to fix it:

```
    val account: GoogleSignInAccount? = completedTask.getResult(ApiException::class.java) 
    updateUI (account!!)
```

You may refer to Kotlin online document [Null Safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) for the details about null and "!!" operator.